# Overwriting an image file (bitmap)

Tags: c#, bitmap, save

Hello I am trying to save a bitmap image in a basic image editor program.

Here's the code:

```
         // then save it
        ImageBoxInApp.Image.Save(filename);
```

**[EDIT]** And I am opening the image with this

```
openFileDialog1.Title = "Select an Image";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files|*.*|Windows Bitmaps|*.bmp|JPEG Files|*.jpg";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename);
```

So when I try this I receive a `Generic GDI+ error`. So I found a [solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312119) to this and it looks like this:

```
        // Delete existing file first
        System.IO.File.Delete(filename);
        // then save it
        ImageBoxInApp.Image.Save(filename);
```

But when I try to do this I receive another error saying that the file I am deleting is currently open. This is because that is the file that I am trying to edit.

How do I "close" the file without actually closing the application? Or is there an alternative solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to say without seeing some context around how your loading the file, but here are a couple of suggestions:

1. Before saving, copy the existing image into a new Image, close the original, perform the delete, and save the copy.
2. Save the file to a random filename, delete the original, rename the randomly named file to the original name.
3. Load the file into a memory stream and use the in memory copy to initialize the image.

I'd personally go with option #3 for most cases.  Be sure to dispose of the image when you've finished using it - it is best if you can wrap it in a using ( ) block.

Comment: 4. instead of creating Image from filename, create Image from stream created from filename and close stream after creating Image (with using() block preferably).

This worked for me and seems better to me.