# Overwrite Existing Image

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I have this code

```
    private void saveImage()
    {
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Image);
        bmp1.Save("c:\\t.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        // Dispose of the image files.
        bmp1.Dispose();
    }
```

i already have an image **t.jpg** at my drive **"c:\"**.
i wanted to replace it with a new image every time my program runs. but a GDI+ error shows up
how could i fix it?

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036115/c-sharp-gdi-overwriting-an-image-using-save-method-of-bitmap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838063/overwriting-an-image-file-bitmap

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You must remove your image if that is already exists.

```
private void saveImage()
    {
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Image);

       if(System.IO.File.Exists("c:\\t.jpg"))
              System.IO.File.Delete("c:\\t.jpg");

        bmp1.Save("c:\\t.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        // Dispose of the image files.
        bmp1.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: this should fix my problem but a new error comes up at `System.IO.File.Delete`. it says, *the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process*

Comment: Have you any other part of code that are working with that file?

Comment: this one `img1 = new Bitmap(@"c:\\t.jpg", true);`. this runs from the start of the program

Comment: You must Dispose img1 before calling this method.

Comment: lot of lights out happens in my country, it's not the best idea.

Comment: Why would you dispose the image? You need the image to save it back to the file system?

Answer (score 6):

I presume you earlier loaded the c:\t.jpg image using the Image.Load method. If so, the Image object is holding an open file handle on the image file, which means that the file can't be overwritten.

Instead of using Image.Load to get the original image, load it from a FileStream that you create and dispose of.

So, instead of

```
Image image = Image.Load(@"c:\\t.jpg");
```

do this:

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\\t.jpg", FileMode.Open))
{
    pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(fs);
    fs.Close();
}
```

The file handle has been released so overwriting the file with Bitmap.Save can succeed. The code you gave in your question should therefore work. There is no need to delete the original file or dispose of the image before saving.

Additional:
If you close the FileStream as above,then calls to Image.Save will throw an exception. See here: [A Generic error occurred in GDI+ in Bitmap.Save method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream)