# removing image reference from picturebox (C#)

Tags: c#, lilypond

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class MyForm : Form
    {
        Process MyProcess;

        public MyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MyForm_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyChar)
            {
                case 'a':
                    this.MyPictureBox.Image = null;
                    this.MyProcess = new Process();
                    this.MyProcess.StartInfo =
                        new ProcessStartInfo("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LilyPond\\usr\\bin\\lilypond.exe\"", "--png tmp.ly");
                    this.MyProcess.Start();
                    this.MyProcess.WaitForExit();
                    this.MyPictureBox.Image = new Bitmap("tmp.png");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\LilyPond\usr\bin\lilypond.exe" --png tmp.ly` command creates `tmp.png`. When I press `a` key first time, MyProcess returns 0, but next - returns 1 always. I think the problem is in overwritting file `tmp.png`, which is using by MyPictureBox, but I have no idea how to repair it. Could you help me?

Comment: Delete it, if it exists. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905714/overwrite-existing-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know lilypond does not give an option for overwriting using a command line argument. If I'm right then you can include code to delete then png file (if exsists) before MyProcess starts.

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
}
```

Comment: Where should I insert that code? After `this.MyPictureBox.Image = null;` in `private void MyForm_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)`? I got IOException (`The process cannot access the file << path >> because it is being used by another process.`)

Comment: For sure before before "MyProcess.Start();" Let's say add it after "case 'a':"

Comment: I'm sorry, but your advice doesn't solve my problem, cause the problem is in using png file by MyPictureBox. I found that good way is using `MyPictureBox.Image.Dispose()` method.

Comment: How about loading the .png using image? "Image image = Image.FromFile(path); MyPictureBox.Image = image;"