# Overwrite image picturebox in C#

Tags: c#

I'm doing one application,
i add a picturebox to add image to some products, i have one question, i would like edit the images already added to one product, how can i do that?
This is my actually code.

```
private void pbImagenEquipo_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ofdImagenes.Filter = "Imagenes JPG (*.jpg)|*.jpg; *.jpeg;|Imagenes PNG (*.png)|*.png";
    DialogResult resp = ofdImagenes.ShowDialog();
    if (resp == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(ofdImagenes.FileName);
        string [] archivo = ofdImagenes.FileName.Split('.');
        nombre = "Equipo_" + lbID+ "." + archivo[archivo.Length-1];

        b.Save(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Imagenes", nombre));

        pbImagenEquipo.Image = b;

    }
}
```

But when i try to replace the image i got this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Error generoc in e GDI+.
```

Comment: By "i would like edit the images already added to one product," do you mean let the user select a new file and overwrite the original file AND update the image in the UI? and what line does the error get thrown at? new Bitmap? b.Save? Image = b?

Comment: @TomA, yes, thats right. " do you mean let the user select a new file and overwrite the original file AND update the image in the UI?"
I have the error on this line:  b.Save(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Imagenes", nombre));

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> Saving the image to the same file it was constructed from is not
>   allowed and throws an exception.

There are two options. One is to delete the file before writing it.

The other is to use a Stream to write it. I prefer the latter..:

```
string fn = "d:\\xyz.jpg";

// read image file
Image oldImg = Image.FromFile(fn);

// do something (optional ;-)
((Bitmap)oldImg).SetResolution(123, 234);

// save to a memorystream
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
oldImg.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

// dispose old image
oldImg.Dispose();

// save new image to same filename
Image newImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
newImage.Save(fn);
```

Note that saving `jpeg` files often achieves better quality if you take control of encoding options. Use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142148%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this..

Also note that since we need to **dispose** of the image you need to make sure that it is not used anywhere, like in a `PictureBox.Image`! If it is, set it to `null` there before disposing : `pictureBox1.Image = null;` !

For a solution deleting the old file see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905714/overwrite-existing-image)