# Cannot delete image in c# even after disposing the image

Tags: c#, file

```
string imagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Resources/image.jpeg");
if (File.Exists(imagePath))
{
    File.Delete(imagePath);
    Debug.WriteLine("image path exists");
}

using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream(binData))
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(imageStream);

    image.Save(imagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    image.Dispose();
}
```

I am getting a `System.IO.IOException` ..The process cannot be accessed as it is already in use

Comment: Which part is causing the IOException? Also, make sure that you don't have the file open in a different program (image viewer, for example).

Comment: When i try to delete it. Also i dont have my image viewer or anything open

Comment: If the exception is occurring at 'File.Delete', then the only explanation is that the file is in use by your code, or there is an open handle on the file. You should check that you are closing the file properly when you use it in other areas of your code.

Comment: Do you have write/delete privileges?

Comment: I doubt you show us all the involved code. If the image is still used anywhere, like in a `PictureBox.Image` or as the `BackgroundImage` of a control it will cling to the original file stream. This is even true if you have cloned the bitmap. The clone will also lock the original file. The way to go would the to create a copy using a memorystream. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736815/overwrite-image-picturebox-in-c-sharp/37741101?s=1|0.0000#37741101) for an example