# PieChart.SaveImage(path,imageFormate) show exception on saving image 2nd time

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop, mschart

I am using Chart Control of **.NET 4.0** framework in Windows Forms Application i have been saving Pie Chart image on location through `PieChart.SaveImage(Path,ChartImageFormat.Png)`, when i create doc file with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` i paste that image in that document. it proceed first time very well and .doc created successfully, but i try to save pie chart 2nd time during win forms Running it give an System.IO.Exception

> "The process cannot access the file 'path' because it is being used by
>   another process."

When i terminate program and run it again it over wright previous image but when i want to save image 2nd time during program running it gives same Exception

This is how i am saving image

```
private Void SavePieChart()
{
    string PieChartPath= Application.StartupPath + @"\Chart.png";
    PieChart.SaveImage(PieChartPath, ChartImageFormat.Png);
}
```

I searched, but did not find any efficient solution which solve my problem,
If anything doing wrong Kindly Point out my mistake, or any helping link to solve this. .

**EDIT 1**

This is where I am pasting that image in Doc file

```
System.Drawing.Image PieChart =System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(PieChartPath);
oHeader1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
Logothread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetImage(PieChart));
Logothread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
Logothread.Start();
Logothread.Join();
oHeader1.Range.Paste();
oHeader1.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
oHeader1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Saving twice should work without a problem. Do you open it in c# as well? If not  suspect that word is still holing on to the image? Does it work when you close word before saving it a 2nd time? Does it work without pasting into  word?

Comment: Try to give all the saved png files a unique name.

Comment: @TaW: I first save image and then paste it into the Doc file, at the end of creation i close the document and quit the application, it works fine. when it try to create doc file 2nd time after some time it shows exception

Comment: @LoekD: it can be done but it will fill the memory in the hard disk, that's why i am not doing  that ...

Comment: I didn't catch the interop part, sorry. So you have the Image open in your app. This means you can't overwrite it unless you first __either__ manage to get rid of __all__ handles or __delete it from the disk__.. A very common issue, usually when changing an image and then trying to overwrite it. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736815/overwrite-image-picturebox-in-c-sharp/37741101?s=1|0.3231#37741101) for a post on how to avoid it in the first place by using a stream to read it, but there are dozens of other post  with other advice as well

Comment: @Taw: no i dont have image Open in my app, any where, i update my Question please check it where i am pasting pie chart in doc file

Comment: does the winword.exe process keep running after you've created the word document?

Comment: @LoekD: No there is no such process running after file is created

Comment: `Image.FromFile` keeps the file in use. You can use `Image.FromStream` instead.

Comment: _System.Drawing.Image PieChart =System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(PieChartPath);_ Well here you __do__ open it. It is not as simple as one would wish to get rid of the handles the .NET system keeps from an FromFile call :-(

Comment: @RezaAghaei: Thanks it solved my problem

Comment: @TaW: thank you dear to pointing out my huge mistake ,, this solve my problem Thanks

Comment: Always glad to help, esp. with such a icky problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is when i wast pasting image in doc file i was take image like

```
System.Drawing.Image PieChart =System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(PieChartPath);
```

as Reza and Taw described FromFile() keeps the file in use so that's why when i try to save image 2nd time it shows exception the file is already in process,

The i use FromStram() add this into my code

```
byte[] DataBytes= System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PieChartPath);
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(DataBytes);

System.Drawing.Image PieChart = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```