# Drawing string on image and save with same name C#

Tags: c#, system.drawing, drawstring

I'm working on a project where I have to draw text from front end using [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com). I have the code to send json for drawing string ie `canvas.tojson()`.

On server side I have a problem in c#. I have to save the image with same filename.  If I try to delete the original file before saving, it says file is already in use by other program, and if I overwrite, it's not doing it either. How can I save file with same name after drawing image?

Here is my code

```
string file = "D:\\Folder\\file.jpg";
            Bitmap bitMapImage = new Bitmap(file);
            Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
            graphicImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            graphicImage.DrawString("That's my boy!",new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold),SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(100, 250));
            graphicImage.DrawArc(new Pen(Color.Red, 3), 90, 235, 150, 50, 0, 360);

            System.IO.File.Delete(file);

            bitMapImage.Save(file, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Also [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736815/overwrite-image-picturebox-in-c-sharp/37741101?s=2|0.0000#37741101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just clone the original bitmap and dispose the original to make it release the file...

```
Bitmap cloneImage = null;
using (Bitmap bitMapImage = new Bitmap(file))
{
    cloneImage = new Bitmap(bitMapImage);
}


using (cloneImage)
{
    Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(cloneImage);
    graphicImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    graphicImage.DrawString("That's my boy!", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(100, 250));
    graphicImage.DrawArc(new Pen(Color.Red, 3), 90, 235, 150, 50, 0, 360);

    System.IO.File.Delete(file);

    cloneImage.Save(file, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803935/free-file-locked-by-new-bitmapfilepath), you can get the bitmap from a file stream and dispose it before changing the image:

```
        Bitmap bitMapImage;
        using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(file, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
        {
            bitMapImage = new Bitmap(fs);
        }

        Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
        graphicImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphicImage.DrawString("That's my boy!",new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold),SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(100, 250));
        graphicImage.DrawArc(new Pen(Color.Red, 3), 90, 235, 150, 50, 0, 360);           

        bitMapImage.Save(file, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```