# c# only Second Bitmap.Save produce A generic error occurred in GDI+ exception

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+, gdi

I am using the following code to compare between two images and save the result.
In the first run I successfully create and save the result image, 
But in the second run I get the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
```

The code:

```
MagickImage magickBaseImg = new MagickImage(new Bitmap(baseImageFileName));
MagickImage magickTargetImg = new MagickImage(new Bitmap(targetImageFileName));

var diffImg = new MagickImage();
magickBaseImg.Compare(magickTargetImg, ErrorMetric.RootMeanSquared, diffImg, Channels.Red);

Bitmap ImgToSave = diffImg.ToBitmap();

DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
String differencesImageSavingPath = @"C:\test\DiffImage" + currentTime.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmm") + ".bmp";
**ImgToSave.Save(differencesImageSavingPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);**

differencesImageFileName = differencesImageSavingPath;
DiffrenceImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(differencesImageFileName));
```

The line that marks with ** is the line that throw the exception in the second run.
Already read and tried fixing it with "using" and .dispose as written here:
[A Generic error occurred in GDI+ in Bitmap.Save method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862810/a-generic-error-occured-in-gdi-in-bitmap-save-method)
and here:
[A generic error occurred in GDI+, JPEG Image to MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream)

But it is not working.

**For Example the following code doesn't work either:**

```
MagickImage magickBaseImg = new MagickImage(new Bitmap(baseImageFileName));
MagickImage magickTargetImg = new MagickImage(new Bitmap(targetImageFileName));

var diffImg = new MagickImage();
magickBaseImg.Compare(magickTargetImg, ErrorMetric.RootMeanSquared, diffImg, Channels.Red);

Bitmap ImgToSave = diffImg.ToBitmap();

DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
String differencesImageSavingPath = @"C:\test\DiffImage" + currentTime.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmm") + ".bmp";

using (var tempImg = new Bitmap(ImgToSave)) {
    tempImg.Save(differencesImageSavingPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
}

differencesImageFileName = differencesImageSavingPath;
DiffrenceImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(differencesImageFileName));
```

Comment: Sure the image isnt open somewhere else?

Comment: tempImg can't be opened - I created a new instance and invoking it also inside"using" statement

Comment: that still doesnt preclude you from using it somewhere else

Comment: You read about it but it is still the same reason. Using using and Dispose does indeed not help. - See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736815/overwrite-image-picturebox-in-c-sharp/37741101?s=25|0.0842#37741101)

Comment: How often do you call that method? As you are saving the image to a filename with minutes and assign it to the DifferenceImage.Source it might be open and therefore writeprotected. The error might not occure if you call the method in different minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why saving the bitmap fails but don't need to make it a bitmap.The Magick.NET library has support for reading and writing BMP images. Below is an example of how you could change your code:

```
using (MagickImage magickBaseImg = new MagickImage(baseImageFileName))
using (MagickImage magickTargetImg = new MagickImage(targetImageFileName))
{
  using (var diffImg = new MagickImage())
  {
    magickBaseImg.Compare(magickTargetImg, ErrorMetric.RootMeanSquared, diffImg, Channels.Red);

    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    string differencesImageSavingPath = @"C:\test\DiffImage" + currentTime.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmm") + ".bmp";
    diffImg.Save(differencesImageSavingPath);

    differencesImageFileName = differencesImageSavingPath;
    DiffrenceImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(differencesImageFileName));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, and @dlemstra had a good clue: using `.ToBitmap()` solved my use case.

Before:

```cs
using (var image = new MagickImage(source))
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Write(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    return (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

After:

```cs
using (var image = new MagickImage(source))
    return image.ToBitmap();
```